# Scipy (Initial provided Hessian with subsequent Hessians from scipy)

Tags: python, scipy

I'm doing a geometry optimization problem where I want to feed BFGS a Jacobian every step (which has been working fine with the "jac = " option,) but I want to give it an initial Hessian which scipy should replace with its own approximate Hessian as soon as it can.  Is there a way to do this?  I'm given to understand that the "hess =" option will force me to either find a new Hessian every step or use the starting Hessian.